# Identifying multiple plants

Tags: identification

It's me again. I'm worried this'll be closed as against the rules, but I didn't find anything against posting multiple plants in one question. Maybe I just didn't look hard enough.

Anyways, here goes. All of these were collected in South-Central Europe, some on fields, some in yards, and some in vineyards or forests. I'll try to give details about each one.

[image]

1) A small plant, found in a field. The ball next to it is the root. It has small bag-like accessories on it.

[image]

2) A woody shrub. From a yard.

[image]

3) Small plant with tiny yellow flowers. Found in a field.

[image]

4) Small green plant with a fairly stiff and thick trunk near the ground. The flowers pop when squeezed. Found in a field.

[image]

5) Small plant found in a field. The trunk is stiff. Small yellow flowers, found in a field.

[image]

6) Small plant with fuzzy leaves. Presumably found in a field. There is one small growth of orange hairs on the left side of the trunk. The main trunk is also quite fuzzy itself.

[image]

7) Small fern. Found near a forest. Apparently, grows in groups with other ferns of the same species and is around 30-40cm tall. The root is very flaky.

[image]

8) See next photo description.

[image]

9) Need help distinguishing two species from the same genus (correct me if I'm wrong but these seem to be from the same genus). The other one is No. 8.

[image]

10) Small plant found in a field. Very flimsy trunk. The leaves are shovel-shaped and there's only one yellow flower with a small number of petals.

[image]

11) Small plant found in a field, many trunks (I'm saying trunk a lot, forgive me, I do not know the proper word) stemming from one central root. The leaves are needle-like just like with a pine but much slimmer.

[image]

12) Small green plant with a very flimsy body. Lilac flowers which stem from the main trunk. The root is very long.

[image]

13) Small green plant found in a field. Leaves are parsley-like and it has flowers which are silk-like to the touch. The body is quite firm and juicy.

Thanks for bearing through this long question. Looking forward to answers.

P.S I can split this into multiple questions, just tell me.

Comment: One plant per question please.

Comment: Hi Quantomic. Yup, we do have a policy of one identification at a time, so please do split them up! When you do, please remember to add basic details to each question. For instance, make sure each one says where you live and any other pertinent data. Feel free to provide links to each question, just as long as the questions can also stand on their own. Once you've split the questions, we'll ask for more details if we need them. Thanks for your cooperation!